# NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, sql, nullpointerexception, java-8

Tenho um botão que pega 2 campos textos e envia para o MySQL pelo padrão MVC só que esta dando um java.lang.NullPointerException q não sei como resolver

O código do botão

```
private void btnCadastraActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    boolean inseriu = false;
    try {
        inseriu = ctrlAdm.insereAdministrador(this.txtNome.getText(), this.txtSenha.getText()); //linha 102
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FrmCadastraUsuario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    if(inseriu){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserido com sucesso");
    }
}
```

A exceção:

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
>   at view.FrmCadastraUsuario.btnCadastraActionPerformed(FrmCadastraUsuario.java:102)
>
>   at view.FrmCadastraUsuario.access$000(FrmCadastraUsuario.java:18)
>   at view.FrmCadastraUsuario$1.actionPerformed(FrmCadastraUsuario.java:48)
>
>   at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>
>   at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>
>   at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>
>   at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>
>   at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>
>   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
>   at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>   at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
>   at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
>
>   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
>
>   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
>
>   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
>   at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>
>   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
>
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
>
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> ```

Comment: Pode indicar qual a linha 102?

Comment: inseriu = ctrlAdm.insereAdministrador(this.txtNome.getText(), this.txtSenha.getText());

Comment: Um dos campos do objeto `FrmCadastraUsuario` não foi inicializado corretamente. Os candidatos são `ctrlAdm`, `txtNome` e `txtSenha`. Bote um _break point_ nessa linha e verifique qual dos Campos está nulo

Comment: resolvi a exceção trocando `private ControlaAdministrador ctrlAdm;`
por `ControlaAdministrador ctrlAdm = new ControlaAdministrador();` 
só que agora ta pegando o banco 33 sendo que o meu é 32 
`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table '3infn33.administrador' doesn't exist`